# Like Box - Showing "check in's" rather than recent posts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, helper

I just added a Facebook Like Box, per the instructions on the developers page here:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

The page says it should show recent posts from the page. However, on my site, it only shows the "friendly activity" feed on the page which seems to be ONLY the people that have checked in to the restaurant. Is it because its a "place" that its doing this? And I may need to make it a business rather than location to adjust the feed?

Is there a settings somewhere that will change this or something? Other wise I have no idea!

Answer (score 6):

Add this parameter to your Like Box code:

```
&force_wall=true
```

The parameter is listed in the "Attributes" section of the [Like Box page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/), but Facebook forgot to include it as an option in the tool that creates the Like Box code.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on this "force_wall - for Places, specifies whether the stream contains posts from the Place's wall or just checkins from friends. Default value: false."

So in the second bit of code (not the script), you will need to add the force_wall parameter similar to this:

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" data-width="595" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-header="true" force_wall="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be data-force-wall="true" , but it still has no effect... it seems this issue really relates to facebook URLs that still use the ".../pages/..." segment